# View tomcat logs azure cloud service

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

Deployed my web app in Azure cloud service using Eclipse Azure Toolkit. I chose tomcat for the application server. App is deployed successfully. But how should I view the tomcat logs for the deployed app? I didn't find any options in azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to azure portal,

1) click 'Web Application', then find you web app and click to get in.

2) go to 'Configuration' page, scroll down, find 'WEB server log record', choose 'Storage'.

3) click 'Manage Storage' to store you log file into a 'Storage'.

4) restart your tomcat, then I think you can see the log files in 'Storage'

Comment: Also you need to click 'open' for 'Application log record(BLOB storage)' and choose 'log record grade' on 'Configuration' page. This is to save your log into a Storage service.

Comment: I didn't deploy my app in App Services, I deployed in cloud services.

Comment: The answer is not helpful for the question

Answer (score 0):

You can create Stream Analytics to collect and filter log :)

Comment: Perhaps you can add more explanation?